# Inline-if inside button triggers deprecation warning and error

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, htmlbars

I'm trying to bind whether a button is `active` or `disabled` on a computed property but get this depcreation warning and error afterwards.

This is troublesome button (Ember 1.11.1 here):

```
<button {{ action 'loadMore' }} {{if canLoadMore 'active' 'disabled'}}>Load More Posts...</button>
```

This warnining and error:

```
DEPRECATION: Returning a string of attributes from a helper inside an element is deprecated.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

on this function:

```
if (value) {
  Ember['default'].deprecate('Returning a string of attributes from a helper inside an element is deprecated.');

  var parts = value.toString().split(/\s+/);
  for (var i = 0, l = parts.length; i < l; i++) {
    var attrParts = parts[i].split('=');
    var attrName = attrParts[0];
    var attrValue = attrParts[1];

    attrValue = attrValue.replace(/^['"]/, '').replace(/['"]$/, '');

    env.dom.setAttribute(domElement, attrName, attrValue);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to set an active class on the button element based on the `canLoadMore` property. In that case, read on.

Your button code evaluates to this something like this html:

```
<button data-ember-action="1234" 'active'>
```

When you probably want this:

```
<button data-ember-action="1234" class='active'>
```

So change your code:

```
<button {{ action 'loadMore' }} {{if canLoadMore 'active' 'disabled'}}>Load More Posts...</button>
```

to:

```
<button {{ action 'loadMore' }} class="{{if canLoadMore 'active' 'disabled'}}">Load More Posts...</button>
```

Comment: This works as intended but what i was trying is to have something like this originally `<button disabled>`

Comment: Ah, in that case check out this jsbin: http://jsfiddle.net/Lehjuw9x/ summary: you need `disabled={{if canLoadMore null 'disabled'}}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<button {{ action 'loadMore' }} 
    class="{{if canLoadMore 'active' 'disabled'}}">Load More Posts...</button>
```

Anyway, the TypeError (that is triggered because your strings dont contain '=' as in `<button {{ action 'loadMore' }} class={{if canLoadMore 'class="active"' 'class="disabled"'}}>Load More Posts...</button>` should not occur (read: a more meaningful error message would be very helpful).

But then it's a deprecated feature that will disappear anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{{bind-attr}}` helper:

```
{{bind-attr class=property:classIfTrue:classIfFalse :classThatDoesntCare}}
```

So your example could be something like:

```
<button {{action "loadMore"}} {{bind-attr class="model.canLoadMore:active:disabled :btn :btn-default"}}>Load More Posts...</button>
```

Comment: `{{bind-attr}}` is deprecated as of Ember version 1.11

Comment: There's an alternative now, but I don't see it being deprecated and I'm not getting any deprecation warnings. Could you provide a link?

[this](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html) doesn't say anything about it being deprecated.

Comment: Sorry, I looked up the deprecation guides and you're right. There's no mention yet about a deprecation of the bind-attr-syntax. I still think it will happen in Ember 2.0